# nasm idiv a negative value

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, integer-division

Trying to divide a positive number by a negative number.

Currently my program will divide correctly, and I can correctly access the remainder.

But when I inputa positive number being divided by a negative value, it wont divide at all.

I know there is a way to "sign extend" and it will divide correctly. I just dont understand the manual

movsss $imm/%reg %reg/mem move, sign extend 231
movzss $imm/%reg %reg/mem move, zero extend

ofcourse thats att syntax, I need intel syntax

here is my code

```
xor rdx, rdx
mov rax, [input]
mov rcx, [input2]
idiv rcx
```

Ideas as how to divide by negative?

Comment: after doing some research I also found an instruction "cdq" that might do it, but hasn't worked yet

Comment: @SepRoland: lol, yes, apparently I hit return *before* control-v or something.

Comment: AT&T version of the same question: [X86 assembly - Handling the IDIV instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10343155) (It forgets to handle RDX entirely, but the answers show the correct `ctqo` ; `idiv` for 64-bit signed division.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the divisor is a signed 64-bit value, you don't need to do anything with it. Likewise, if the dividend is a signed 128-bit value, you don't need to do anything with it, just load the top 64 bits of it into `rdx` and the low 64 bits into `rax`.

Now, if any of the numbers is signed but shorter than `idiv` expects, you need to sign-extend that number. Sign extension is very simple. You just fill the vacant top bits with the most significant bit (sign bit) of your number. For non-negative numbers you fill that space with 0's and for negative numbers you fill it with 1's. There are a few instructions available that can sign-extend the value currently held in the accumulator. They are: `cbw`, `cwde`, `cdqe`, `cwd`, `cdq`, `cqo`. The last three sign extend into `dx/edx/rdx`. Most likely you need `cqo` instead of `xor rdx, rdx` like this:

```
mov rax, [input]
cqo ; sign extends rax into rdx:rax
mov rcx, [input2]
idiv rcx
```

As for *'But when I inputa positive number being divided by a negative value, it wont divide at all'*, it can't be. It either divides or invokes a division exception (division by 0 or overflow), there's no third option.

Comment: cqo worked!!!, i was trying cdq for a while and it didn't work, by chance can you point me to the source you used to figure that out?

Comment: In this document (from amd.com): AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual Volume 3: General-Purpose and System Instructions.

Comment: @user1050632 Because there are already `cwd` (convert word to double word) and `cdq` (convert double to quad word) one can expect to find a 64 bit instruction like `cqo` (convert quad to oct word) or something similar named.