# Why isn't my IDIV instruction working as expected on Windows x64 using NASM assembler?

Tags: windows, assembly, 64-bit, nasm, integer-division

I tried using the below assembly code to get the quotient and remainder for IDIV instruction, but it didn't work as expected. I use NASM as the assembler.
It prints "The quotient is: -1840700272The remainder is: 1".
I have tried cbq, cbw, etc.. Nothing works.

```
bits 64

default rel

section .data

    quotientMsg db "The quotient is: %d", 0
    remainderMsg db "The remainder is: %d", 0

section .bss

    remainder resd 1

section .text

    extern printf
    global main
    extern _CRT_INIT

main:

    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32
    call    _CRT_INIT

    ; Perform signed division
    mov rax, -15
    mov rcx, 7
    xor rdx, rdx  ; Clear RDX to zero for the remainder
    idiv rcx
    
    ; Store the remainder in a reserved space
    mov dword [remainder], edx

    ; Print the quotient
    mov rcx, quotientMsg
    mov edx, eax
    call printf

    ; Print the remainder
    mov rcx, remainderMsg
    mov edx, dword [remainder]
    call printf

    ; Exit the program
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

The expected result should be -2 (quotient) and 1 (remainder).

Comment: It's an exact duplicate of [nasm idiv a negative value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9072922); I edited the duplicate list after the initial closure, but before your last edit.  If you're printing the result properly, `cqo` works to sign-extend RAX into RDX:RAX before `idiv`.  It's weird that you're doing slow 64-bit division but only using the low 32 bits of the quotient and remainder, but should work for small values.  (Truncating the bit-pattern like you're doing is the correct way to do a narrowing integer conversion in 2's complement.)

Comment: Also, you could use one format string with two conversions and only call `printf` once, making your program simpler.

Comment: Also, your comment on `xor rdx, rdx  ; Clear RDX to zero for the remainder` doesn't make sense.  You're not zeroing it because that's where the remainder will go, you're zeroing it as an input to IDIV, the high half of the quotient.  (But of course zero-extension isn't the right thing to do for signed inputs.)  The linked duplicates also explain that.